# How do you return a menu with the menu name?

Tags: menus

in functions.php, I've defined the following:

```
register_nav_menu( 'home_blocks', __( 'Home Page Posts', 'my_Theme' ) );
```

In `/wp-admin/nav-menus.php`, I've added a menu called Home Page Posts and assigned 3 posts to it and set it to be the item associated with Home Page Posts as the menu location.

In `index.php`, I've added the following:

```
if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) {
    echo 'has primary<br />';
} else {
    echo 'no primary<br />';
}
if ( has_nav_menu( 'home_blocks' ) ) {
    echo 'has home blocks<br />';
} else {
    echo 'no home_blocks<br />';
}
```

Both of the successful conditions are echoed.

When I try to return the menu contents so I can run some inline custom output based on post_id, I attempted the following code and got NULL or string(0) "", depending on what values I put for the location and menu name.  What way are these values associated and how would I get the menu back?

```
$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => 'home_blocks',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => '',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => '',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => 1,
    'fallback_cb'     => '',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);

$menu = wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

var_dump( $menu );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return the output of `wp_nav_menu()`, instead of echo-ing it, you should replace

```
'echo'            => 1,
```

with

```
'echo'            => 0,
```

Then you should get something out of `var_dump( $menu );`.

You can read more about the input parameters in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Parameters).

**Update:**

You should remove this line:

```
'items_wrap'      => '',
```

to use the default which is:

```
'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
```

You can also target a specific menu with the `'menu'` parameter, if you haven't selected a location for it, in the menu settings page. Currently you have it set to `''`;

Comment: Hi, I tried 1 and 0, true and false there, but it still returned NULL. I found a way around it by listing the menus and fetching the items in it and the contents of those items. I still can't identify why the menu's not directly output with combinations of the above.

Comment: Please check out the `'items_wrap'` part of your settings, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$menu = wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'home_blocks', 'echo' => 0) );
var_dump($menu); //works just fine
```

You are essentially overriding all the defaults that wp_nav_menu has when you make an array and assign its values to an empty string.

Delete that default array and only set the items you need like in the example I have in the array above.